# Django ORM Facing issue in Group By in 3 levels of table

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Models:

- Employee - name, email
- CuttingJob - employee (ForeignKey), count
- OrderCuttingDetail - product_name, amount

I want to show the employee wise cutting count and it’s amount.

```
employees = Employee.objects.annotate(
total_cutting_job_count=Sum(‘cutting_jobs__count’),
total_cutting_job_amount=ExpressionWrapper(F(‘total_cutting_job_count’) * F(‘cutting_jobs__order_cutting_detail__amount’), output_field=DecimalField()),
).all()
```

But while running this query, employees are duplicated. Need to group the records based on employee’s name.

Kindly suggest a solution for this.

I want to show the total amount based on employee wise. Kindly provide a solution for this.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by name, you simply need to add `.values("name")` **BEFORE** the `.annotate()`  [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values)

```
employess = Employee.objects.values("name")
employees = employees.annotate(
total_cutting_job_count=Sum(‘cutting_jobs__count’),
total_cutting_job_amount=ExpressionWrapper(F(‘total_cutting_job_count’) * F(‘cutting_jobs__order_cutting_detail__amount’), output_field=DecimalField()),
)
```

Note that this will get rid of the Model layer since if does note make sense anymore (because of the grouping), you'll get a dict with three keys "name", "total_cutting_job_count", and "total_cutting_job_count"